# Version and Build are reset after "cordova build ios"

Tags: xcode, cordova

I'm using Cordova to build my ios app.
My problem is that every time I execute "cordova build ios" from the terminal, the fields 'Version' and 'Build' in Xcode are reset to 1.0.0:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can configure this version in your `config.xml`. Have a look at the `<widget>` tag in there.

```
<widget id="your.bundle.id" ios-CFBundleVersion="2.0.0" version="2.0.0" android-versionCode="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

The `version` property lets you define the version displayed in the app store and the `CFBundleVersion` property specifies the build-version.

The version codes you see in XCode are reset every time you do a build because *everything* in the `platforms/ios` folder is regenerated/updated everytime you build your project.